# Are there an Observer and an Event Handler to respond to file modification in python?

Tags: python, events, server

I have HTML code that talks to a server(just a php script) and writes user input to a json file. However, now I want to write python that notices when the json file is modified and reads the new value. I looked around and found references to watchdog and a lot of examples, but all of the examples seemed to throw the same error every time I modified the file. Here is one of the examples(the others are not noticeably different):

```py
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print event


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "/PATH/TO/YOUR/FOLDER"
    event_handler = EventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

The error gave the path to the json file, then `Bad file descriptor`(it did this once for each directory in the file path). I looked into that, and it is caused by my modifying the Json file from outside the code(which I was doing from a text editor for testing purposes), which was what was going to happen anyway with the PHP Script. The way I see it, there are two ways to go on this problem. Either somehow connect the python and php so that the python is a part of the server, or find a new method of event watching in the file system. What do I do?

Comment: if it helps, there were other error messages mentioning kqueue

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It is  possible to connect php to python. Essentially, both can use a standardized output stream, such that when you print in python, it gets put into the php, so the connection works both ways. Here's how you do it. In the php, get your variables set up, then use the shell_exec command:

```php
$variableToPassToPython="hi";
$result=shell_exec('Path to python that you use Path to py file that you want to run ' . $variableToPassToPython);
//that will concatenate the variable to the terminal command(shell_exc runs terminal commands) to be sent to the python as an arg
```

now, to access variables passed to the python in the command line, do this in the python:

```py
   import sys
   hi=sys.argv[1]#argv[0] is the path of the python file, and argv returns a list of all arguments passed through command line
print(hi+' world!')
#remember that in this case, printing means sending something back to the php file
```

This lets you do cool stuff in the php(the below code assumes you already ran the python in the above code):

```php
echo $result
//result was the variable that was assigned to the shell_exec command, and that command returns whatever python prints to it
```

The above code will look like this:

```html
hi world!
```

You can see how this opens up many more doors than just that

**IMPORTANT:**
I had a problem with doing this initially. If you are using input from a POST request in your php, that is an array, and shell_exec casts to a string. In php, when you cast an array to a string, it becomes just the word "Array". To fix this, use the implode() function, which properly turns an array into a string so it can be passed as a shell command